# Regular expression to delete HTML strings

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to delete part of a string that does not match my pattern. For example, in

```
<SYNC Start=364><P Class=KRCC>
<Font Color=lightpink>abcd
```

I would like to delete

```
<P Class=KRCC><Font Color=lightpink>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: We have no idea what you mean by "my pattern". You need to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match `your pattern' and write that to a file or update the table of a database. That way, you are *deleting* the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not indicate that you need (or should use) regular expressions. If you want to remove a fixed string, do traditional search and replace.

Comment: I agree, if you can use replace string function you will get performance benefit too

Comment: ... and if you want to remove HTML nodes, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML you are parsing is valid and always follows a known standard format, you can use non-greedy patterns to remove most of what you don't want.

*These samples will have to be modified based on the tool/framework you're using to handle regular expressions. I am not escaping special characters for brevity.*

To match any paragraph tags:

```
<p.*?>(.*?)</p>
```

You would replace these matches with $1 (or whatever your syntax requires to access groups).

It's important to use non-greedy (?) patterns to avoid accidentally matching two unrelated start/end tags. For example:

```
<p.*>(.*)</p>
```

Would behave very differently. In the case of the following example HTML, it would not correctly match two paragraphs:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
```

Instead, it would match "`<p>Lorem ipsum.</p><p>`" as the first portion, which would result in losing content.

If you need to match paragraphs with specific classes, you could use something like this:

```
<p.*?class="delete".*?>(.*?)</p>
```

Where things get sticky is when you start working with non-standardized HTML. For example, this is all valid HTML, but the pattern to clean it up would be ugly:

```
<p>no class</p>
<p class=delete>no quotes</p>
<p class="delete">double quotes</p>
<p class='delete'>single quotes</p>
<p>space in closing tag</p >
<p>no closing tag
```

Comment: Actually, I thought recommending regex to parse HTML was off limits.